# Calling instance method recursively in python

Tags: python, recursion, python-2.7

I'm trying to call the instance method of objects inside a dictionary who have the objects themselves, all are from the same class. But i have a infinite recursion, i think that 'self' doesn't change and reference the first object all the time.

```
class Foo():
    name = 'name'
    foo_objects = {}
    def print_name(self):
        output = self.name
        for key, value in self.foo_objects.items():
            output += value.print_name()
        return output
```

I'm using it like this:

```
def main():
    foo = Foo()
    foo.foo_objects['key'] = Foo()
    print foo.print_name()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

And i get this error:

```
  ...etc...
    output += value.print_name()
  File "C:\dev\python\projects\test\test.py", line 41, in print_name
    output += value.print_name()
  File "C:\dev\python\projects\test\test.py", line 41, in print_name
    output += value.print_name()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

What´s wrong? What I'm not understanding of python recursion? How can be do?
Thanks for any help, and excuse me my bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined name and foo_objects as class variables, not instance variables -- i.e. they are currently shared between all instances of the Foo class.

Change:

```
class Foo():
  name = 'name'
  foo_objects = {}
...
```

to:

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'name'
    self.foo_objects = {}
...
```

and they will become instance variables as I suspect you wanted them to be.

Comment: Thanks!!, Now i know about class attributes and instance attributes in python.